# Перемещение обьектов

Tags: c++, c++11

В каких случаях компилятор неявно создает конструктор перемещения и соответствующий оператор присвоения?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конструктор перемещения и соответствующий оператор генерируются (`= default`) по умолчанию для всех классов, за исключением случаев, когда в классе явно определена хотя бы одна из нижеследующих сущностей:

- Конструктор копирования/перемещения
- Оператор копирования/перемещения
- Деструктор